# UI templating library built in LitElement

Tags: web-component, custom-element, lit-element, uicomponents, html-components

I'm looking for a UI components/templating library that's built with LitElement. I've already checked Aybolit (https://github.com/web-padawan/aybolit) but it has very limited number of components. I need a library like Carbon design systems but built with LitElement.

If there's any library that is **Lightweight**, **Built with LitElement** and have a considerable number of components available then please do suggest.

Answer (score 4):

It really shouldn't matter whether web components are implemented with LitElement if they meet your other requirements. If Carbon had a set of standard, interoperable web components built with another library, they should be fine to use from within components built with LitElement.

As it turns out though, Carbon's web components implementation *is* built with LitElement : https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-custom-elements

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

The best library by far done with lit-element and lightweight is Material

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components